# friend, i have tried to insert data from a HTML form into a Mysql database but it's not working, also unable to find the error

Tags: php, html, mysql

There is some kind of error in the code, I am unable to spot it. The connection with the database is working OK, I can verify that

**here is the HTML code**
in HTML I have created a form to insert the data into the database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">

    <form method="post" name="Draw" action="form/insertdata.php">

        <input type="date" name="form_fields[date]  " >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[am113d]" >               

        <input type="number" name="form_fields[am112d]">        
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[am111d]" >               
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm13d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm12d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm11d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm53d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm52d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm51d]">
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm63d]">
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm62d]">
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm61d]">
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm73d]">
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm72d]" >
        <input type="number" name="form_fields[pm71d]" >

        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
</html>
```

**here is the PHP code**

This is the PHP code to collect the data from the HTML form and store it into MySql database

***If I use this code only an empty row is getting inserted into the database, the value entered in the form is not getting inserted ***

```
<?php

    include_once 'Configuration.php';

    $Dateee = $_POST['form_fields[date]'];
    $am113d = $_POST['form_fields[am113d]'];
    $am112d = $_POST['form_fields[am112d]'];
    $am111d = $_POST['form_fields[am111d]'];
    $pm13d = $_POST['form_fields[pm13d]'];
    $pm12d = $_POST['form_fields[pm12d]'];
    $pm11d = $_POST['form_fields[pm11d]'];
    $pm53d = $_POST['form_fields[pm53d]'];
    $pm52d = $_POST['form_fields[pm52d]'];
    $pm51d = $_POST['form_fields[pm51d]'];
    $pm63d = $_POST['form_fields[pm63d]'];
    $pm62d = $_POST['form_fields[pm62d]'];
    $pm61d = $_POST['form_fields[pm61d]'];
    $pm73d = $_POST['form_fields[pm73d]'];
    $pm72d = $_POST['form_fields[pm72d]'];
    $pm71d = $_POST['form_fields[pm71d]'];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Draw_tabel` 
        (`Date`, `A113d`, `A112d`, `A111d`, `A133d`, `A132d`, `A131d`, `A173d`, `A172d`, `A171d`, `A183d`, `A182d`, `A181d`, `A193d`, `A192d`, `A191d`) 
        VALUES 
        ('$Dateee', '$am113d', '$am112d', '$am111d', '$pm13d', '$pm12d', '$pm11d', '$pm53d', '$pm52d', '$pm51d', '$pm63d', '$pm62d', '$pm61d', '$pm73d', '$pm72d', '$pm71d');";


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

**database**

this is the SQL code to create a MySql database

```
CREATE TABLE `Draw_data`.`Draw_tabel` ( 
    `Date` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A113d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A112d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A111d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A133d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A132d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A131d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A173d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A172d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A171d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A183d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A182d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A181d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A193d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A192d` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `A191d` TEXT NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: if you `var_dump( $_POST )` before trying to input to db does it show the correct / expected data?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not advocating that this is good practice but for demonstration purposes to show what is wrong with your code I'll put this here "as-is" - though it really, really ought to be done using a `prepared statement`!!!

The form is submitting an `array` so effectively you were accessing the data at the wrong level. You need to access the fields found within the `form_fields` array rather than the `POST` array as such ( though of course `form_fields` is in the POST array )

For simplicity the various values are assigned here as variables using `variable variable` syntax

```
$fields=$_POST['form_fields'];
foreach( $fields as $field => $value )${$field}=$value;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `Draw_tabel` 
    (`Date`, `A113d`, `A112d`, `A111d`, `A133d`, `A132d`, `A131d`, `A173d`, `A172d`, `A171d`, `A183d`, `A182d`, `A181d`, `A193d`, `A192d`, `A191d`) 
    VALUES 
    ('$date', '$am113d', '$am112d', '$am111d', '$pm13d', '$pm12d', '$pm11d', '$pm53d', '$pm52d', '$pm51d', '$pm63d', '$pm62d', '$pm61d', '$pm73d', '$pm72d', '$pm71d');";


echo $sql;
```

the final rendered SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `Draw_tabel` 
    (`Date`, `A113d`, `A112d`, `A111d`, `A133d`, `A132d`, `A131d`, `A173d`, `A172d`, `A171d`, `A183d`, `A182d`, `A181d`, `A193d`, `A192d`, `A191d`) 
VALUES 
    ('2020-12-12', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '78', '45', '12', '99', '56', '45', '12', '115', '0');
```

The numbers are meaningless here - just simple integers randomly typed.

---

A better way to do this would be, as mentioned, to use a `prepared statement` which might be done like so:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['form_fields'] ) ){


    $fields=$_POST['form_fields'];
    $types=array();
    $values=array();

    foreach( $fields as $field => $value ){
        $values[]=$value;
        $types[]=is_numeric( $value ) ? 'i' : 's';
    }


    $sql='insert into `draw_tabel` 
        (`date`, `a113d`, `a112d`, `a111d`, `a133d`, `a132d`, `a131d`, `a173d`, `a172d`, `a171d`, `a183d`, `a182d`, `a181d`, `a193d`, `a192d`, `a191d`) 
        values 
        ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? );';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param( implode('',$types), ...$values );
    $res=$stmt->execute();

    echo $res ? 'New record created successfully' : 'Error';
}
```

Comment: Types should always be string. Checking if value is numeric could lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: what then is the point of multiple type identifiers if they should only be strings?

Comment: Rare cases when you really want the type to match. But it should be done based on the DB column type, not the input type.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> ```
> <input type="date" name="form_fields[date]  " >
> ```

and

> ```
> $Dateee = $_POST['form_fields[date]'];
> ```

but PHP will take that field name and put it in:

```
$_POST['form_fields']['date']
```

… and you have similar errors for all your other fields.

---

You should also [use prepared statements with placeholders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of mashing user input into strings of SQL.